# Show that the system $x'=x(4-y-x^2)$, $y'=y(x-1)$, has no closed orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Show that this system has no closed orbit: $$x'=x(4-y-x^2)\qquad y'=y(x-1)$$

I try to solve the problem by using Dulac's criterion but it seems that I wander. Shortly I fail to find the finding Lyapunov functions $V(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks to edit my question.

Comment: The way how nullclines are located in II-IV quadrants prevents having closed orbit. Note that solutions that correspond to closed orbits are periodic: this means that if they are non-constant they have to intersect both nullclines at least twice. That's impossible in these quadrants. The interesting part is the first quadrant: if the closed orbit exists, it must encircle equilibrium at $(1, 3)$. So, if you want to do this with Lyapunov function of Dulac's criterion, you have to worry about only the first quadrant.

Comment: To eliminate the possibility of closed orbits in the quadrant $(x>0,y>0)$, consider $$V(x,y)=x+y-\ln x-3\ln y\qquad v(t)=V(x(t),y(t))$$ and note that
$$v'(t)=-(x(t)-1)^2(x(t)+1)\leqslant0$$